# Dart Regexp replace all but numbers and allow once . or ,

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, currency

I need to replace everything that is not a number and allow only the first `,` or `.`.

```
final string = _lengthController.text?.replaceAll(RegExp('[^0-9,.]'), '')
```

This is what I got so far and its working fine but will allow `,` `.` more than once.

So how can I replace every `,` and `.` after the first one, not one of each but only one in total is allowed.

Comment: I understand `r'(?<=\..*)\.|[^0-9,.]+'` won't work, right?

Comment: no its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```dart
text.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'^([^,.]*[.,])|\D+'), (Match m) => 
   m[1] != null ? m[1].replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9,.]+'), '') : '')
```

The `^([^.,]*[.,])|\D+` regex matches

- `^([^,.]*[.,])` - start of string and then any chars other than `,` and `.` and then a `.` or `,` captured into Group 1
- `|` - or
- `\D+` - any one or more non-digit chars.

If the first alternative matches, the `,` and `.` should be preserved, so `.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9,.]+'), '')` is used to remove all chars other than digits, `.` and `,`.

If `\D+` matches, it means the first `.` or `,` has already been matched, so the replacement for this alternative is an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, its working fine for the `.` but not working at all for the `,`

Comment: @StevenDz Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @StevenDz And what do you expect? `32,,43` is correctly (because you asked to *"replace every `,` and `.` after the first one, not one of each but only one in total is allowed"*) converted to `32,43`. `321,32` must stay the same.

Comment: for me its not converted (Flutter1.26.0-12.0.pre, Dart 2.12.0 )

Comment: @StevenDz Are you sure you are using my code? You must use raw string literals, `r'...'`,  when defining the regex patterns.

Comment: @StevenDz Ok, at any rate, my code works fine. There is something in yours that interferes with the replacing.

Comment: Sorry its working fine, there was another expeption thrown because its not a double with `,` and so the ui didnt updated. So I need to replace the `,` with `.`

Thank you